# Find offset exported function in DLL file

Tags: c++, dll, reverse-engineering, patch, portable-executable

In order to apply hot fixes to a DLL I used 'LoadLibrary' and
'GetProcAddress' to find base address and offset of an exported
function in a DLL. Example:

```
// Use Handle as base address
base = LoadLibrary(...);

// Get offset relative to base
offset = GetProcAddress(...);
```

and using it this way:

```
// Calculate offset in file
offsetInFile = offset - base;

// Apply hotfix in file
PatchExportedFunction(offsetInFile, "MyDLL.dll");
```

This worked fine so far - however I now have the problem that
there are some DLLs that are different in a way that the calculated
offset does not match the offset in the file anymore.

Obviously my approach for finding the function is too simple but
I have no clue what I'm missing and why it works most of the
time but not always.

Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: You can get the base address explicitly through `GetModuleInformation`, but even the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that it's the same as the HMODULE.

Comment: Yes. But I don't want the base address but the address of a function in memory but in the file.

Comment: There might be another level of redirection, so that the function address is just a jump to the real location of the function. Might be difficult to decode that. Maybe have a look at the disassembly.